# Error while creating Azure storage blob via Terraform

Tags: azure, terraform

I am facing an issue while creating a blob via the below *terraform script*.

```
provider "azurerm" {
  subscription_id = ""
  client_id       = ""
  client_secret   = ""
  tenant_id       = ""
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "test" {
    name = "samplevhdtestrg"
    location = "Central US"
}

resource "azurerm_storage_account" "test" {
    name = "acctestacc"
    resource_group_name = "${azurerm_resource_group.test.name}"
    location = "westus"
    account_type = "Standard_LRS"
}

resource "azurerm_storage_container" "test" {
    name = "vhds"
    resource_group_name = "${azurerm_resource_group.test.name}"
    storage_account_name = "${azurerm_storage_account.test.name}"
    container_access_type = "private"
}

resource "azurerm_storage_blob" "testsb" {
    name = "sample.vhd"

    resource_group_name = "${azurerm_resource_group.test.name}"
    storage_account_name = "${azurerm_storage_account.test.name}"
    storage_container_name = "${azurerm_storage_container.test.name}"
    source_uri = "https://samplevhdtestrg.blob.core.windows.net/system/Microsoft.Compute/Images/images2/d054f6c4-3827-434c-8733-785785ff12ed.vhd"

    type = "page"
    size = 5120
}
~
```

Here I'm trying to clone an existing vhd into the newly creating blob. But I get below validation failure in 'terraform plan'

> azurerm_storage_blob.testsb: : invalid or unknown key: source_uri

I tried with 'source' attribute value to copy a vhd from file system also. But it also fails, giving below error

> azurerm_storage_blob.testsb: : invalid or unknown key: source

My intention here is to create a custom ubuntu image to refer as the vhd of the newly creating VM. Any help on this is highly appreciated.

Comment: What version of Terraform are you running?

Comment: Hmmm.. not sure then. The `source` and `source_uri` keys were added in 0.7.1 so should be fine. I don't have an Azure account to test with but that error looks very odd if you are running 0.7.1+. Checking the history on resource_arm_storage_blob.go shows that those keys haven't changed since that release.